# Composer not found error after installing composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have installed composer following all the steps of installation and also created project directory but after restarting  the computer I tried to run  composer command but still getting the same error 'composer command not found'......... before restarting computer it successfully ran composer command

Comment: Please specify which "all steps" you followed to install composer.

Comment: This are the steps from composer official website                                       php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '544e09ee996cdf60ece3804abc52599c22b1f40f4323403c44d44fdfdd586475ca9813a858088ffbc1f233e9b180f061') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;" php composer-setup.php php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" sry for not editing properly

Comment: Did editing on mobile app

Answer (score 5):

The code from your comment only *installs* setup script, which you should find as `composer-setup.php` in your folder. Use this command to install composer:

```
php composer-setup.php
```

After this is done, use `php composer.phar` to execute Composer. If you want to install it globally (recommended) use

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

You can just execute Composer by `composer` on the CLI.